# Show that every non-trivial solution to the differential equation has at most one zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that every nontrivial solution to the equation $y''-e^x y=0$ can have at most one zero on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

I assume that the solution has a two zeros $x_1 < x_2$  such that $y(x)>0$ (say) for $x \in (x_1,x_2)$.

But, How to that no compatible with $y''(x)=e^x y(x) $ for $x \in (x_1,x_2)$?
(How do I get into contradiction?)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $y$ is convex when $y > 0$ and concave when $y < 0$.